# Blob not displaying in Safari 11

Tags: javascript, safari, base64, blob

I am using b64-to-blob and the function below to convert base64 images to blobs and injecting them into the html. This works fine accross all the browsers I have tested except for Safari 11. I can't seem to find any solution on Google.

The HTML file is stand-alone and needs to work locally without a server.

Any help would be appreciated.

b64-to-blob Function:

```
(function(root, globalName, factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD:
    define([], factory);
  } else if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
    // Node:
    module.exports = factory();
    // Use module export as simulated ES6 default export:
    module.exports.default = module.exports;
  } else {
    // Browser:
    window[globalName] = factory();
  }
}(this, 'b64toBlob', function() {
  'use strict';

  return function b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
    contentType = contentType || '';
    sliceSize = sliceSize || 512;

    var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
    var byteArrays = [];

    for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
      var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

      var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
      for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
        byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
      }

      var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

      byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }

    var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
    return blob;
  };
}));
```

hooked Function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var contentTypePng = 'image/png';
  var favicon =
      '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';

      var contentTypeJpg = 'image/jpg';
      var imageSrcOne =
          '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';

  var faviconBlob = b64toBlob(favicon, contentTypePng);
  var faviconBlobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(faviconBlob);

  var imageOneBlob = b64toBlob(imageSrcOne, contentTypeJpg);
  var imageOneBlobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(imageOneBlob);

  var blob1 = faviconBlobUrl;
  var blob2 = imageOneBlobUrl;

  // document.querySelector('#favicon').href = blob1;
  // document.querySelector('#imageOne').src = blob2;

  $('#favicon').attr('href', blob1);
  $('#imageOne').attr('src', blob2);
});
```

Example output in browser (Locally viewing index.html):

```
<img id="imageOne" src="blob:null/6cab2520-7a96-4cd4-b94d-d1cf3d58baae" alt="">
```

Comment: In Safari Resources Console the full url is displayed along with the Mime type although under Request and Response it throws an error: Unknown Error

Comment: Also on the HTML image tag the blob url is not inserted (in Safari): <img id="imageOne" src="" alt="">

Answer (score 0):

I scrapped the blobs and took a different approach with Base64 image conversion which is now working across all browsers.

Ref:

```
http://dataurl.net/#dataurlmaker
```